# How to separate flask app.route order of events

Tags: python, flask

I have a small program that opens up an outlook email when a button is clicked on an html page. The problem is, I don't know the order of my app.route objects and the posted data from my html page.

My html (openemailJS.html):

my flask app:

```
import win32com.client
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, json, url_for, request, redirect
import pythoncom, time, os, sys

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
   if request.method == 'POST':
       emailid = request.args.get('nm')
       time.sleep(1)
       pythoncom.CoInitialize()
       outlook = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNameSpace('MAPI')
       inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
       sentbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(5)
       all_sentbox = sentbox.Items
       all_inbox = inbox.Items
       tryopen = outlook.GetItemFromID(emailid)
       tryopen.display()
       return render_template('openemailJS.html')
       print(emailid)
   else:
        time.sleep(1)
        emailid = request.args.get('nm')
        #emailid = request.form.get('nm')
        time.sleep(1)
        pythoncom.CoInitialize()
        outlook = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNameSpace('MAPI')
        inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
        sentbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(5)
        all_sentbox = sentbox.Items
        all_inbox = inbox.Items
        tryopen = outlook.GetItemFromID(emailid)
        tryopen.display()
        print(user)
        return render_template('openemailJS.html')
```

I think I need to separate the ' return render_template('openemailJS.html') 'into its own app.route('/something here/') but I don't know how to do that.

Currently, when I run it how it is, the emailid does not get posted before the def index(): runs, causing a 'parameter not found' where it should be. If I comment out everything but the 'return render_template', run the program, and then uncommment it out and click the button, then it gets posted as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I added an if statement to retrieve the data only if the form is posted. I still think it makes sense to render the template first before doing anything, but I don't know.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).